# What is the difference between IVsTextViewCreationListener and IWpfTextViewCreationListener

Tags: .net, vs-extensibility

Am looking into some examples such as [this one on code project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1245021/Extending-Visual-Studio-to-Provide-a-Colorful-Lang) where it uses [IVsTextViewCreationListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.editor.ivstextviewcreationlistener) and [this walkthrough on ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-customizing-the-text-view) where it talks about [IWpfTextViewCreationListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextviewcreationlistener)

What is the difference between them and when to use what? First felt that there would be some common ancestor something like **ITextViewCreationListener**, but there isn't.

What is a text view? There is [IWpfTextView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextview), then there is [IVsTextView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextview) and also there is [ITextView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.itextview)

[IWpfTextView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextview) derives from [ITextView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.itextview) but [IVsTextView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextview) does not.

I gained some idea about [IWpfTextView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextview) and [ITextView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.itextview) from
[the article **Inside the editor** here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/inside-the-editor).

I am still not clear about [IVsTextView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextview).

Kindly throw some light in simple words.